# How to compute the probability of a multi-class prediction using libsvm?

Tags: java, machine-learning, probability, svm, libsvm

I'm using [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/index.html) and the documentation leads me to believe that there's a way to output the believed probability of an output classification's accuracy.  Is this so?  And if so, can anyone provide a clear example of how to do it in code?

Currently, I'm using the Java libraries in the following manner

```
    SvmModel model = Svm.svm_train(problem, parameters);
    SvmNode x[] = getAnArrayOfSvmNodesForProblem();
    double predictedValue = Svm.svm_predict(model, x);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given your code-snippet, I'm going to assume you want to use the Java API packaged with [libSVM](http://latent.homeunix.org/javadoc/libSVM/), rather than the more verbose one provided by [jlibsvm](http://dev.davidsoergel.com/trac/jlibsvm/).

To enable prediction with probability estimates, train a model with the **svm_parameter field** [***probability***](http://latent.homeunix.org/javadoc/libSVM/libsvm/svm_parameter.html#probability)  **set to 1**. Then, just change your code so that it calls the **svm method [`svm_predict_probability`](http://latent.homeunix.org/javadoc/libSVM/libsvm/svm.html#svm_predict_probability)** rather than `svm_predict`.

Modifying your snippet, we have:

```
parameters.probability = 1;
svm_model model = svm.svm_train(problem, parameters);

svm_node x[] = problem.x[0]; // let's try the first data pt in problem
double[] prob_estimates = new double[NUM_LABEL_CLASSES]; 
svm.svm_predict_probability(model, x, prob_estimates);
```

It's worth knowing that training with multiclass probability estimates **can change the predictions** made by the classifier. For more on this, see the question [Calculating Nearest Match to Mean/Stddev Pair With LibSVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567483/calculating-nearest-match-to-mean-stddev-pair-with-libsvm/2570217#2570217).

Comment: @dmcer Which package has the smaller learning curve (the Java API packaged with libSVM or jlibsvm)? I'm a newbie to SVMs in general.

Comment: @rohanbk - probably jlibsvm, since it looks and feels like a typical Java API.

Comment: @dmcer Do you have any experience with using WEKA for SVMs?

Comment: @rohanbk - Not too much. But, it would be a reasonably good choice, since it would allow you to easily benchmark other classifiers on your data.

Comment: @dmcer Thanks for the advice. I think I'll pursue the jlibsvm approach. Do you know of any good resources/examples that I can use to learn about jlibsvm? There seems to be a definite dearth of examples.

Comment: @rohanbk - The only good sample code I know of is the "legacyexec" command line tools: http://dev.davidsoergel.com/trac/jlibsvm/browser/trunk/src/main/java/edu/berkeley/compbio/jlibsvm/legacyexec

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer worked like a charm. Make sure to set `probability = 1` during training.

If you are trying to drop prediction when the confidence is not met with threshold, here is the code sample:

```
double confidenceScores[] = new double[model.nr_class];
svm.svm_predict_probability(model, svmVector, confidenceScores);

/*System.out.println("text="+ text);
for (int i = 0; i < model.nr_class; i++) {
    System.out.println("i=" + i + ", labelNum:" + model.label[i] + ", name=" + classLoadMap.get(model.label[i]) + ", score="+confidenceScores[i]);
}*/

//finding max confidence; 
int maxConfidenceIndex = 0;
double maxConfidence = confidenceScores[maxConfidenceIndex];
for (int i = 1; i < confidenceScores.length; i++) {
    if(confidenceScores[i] > maxConfidence){
        maxConfidenceIndex = i;
        maxConfidence = confidenceScores[i];
    }
}

double threshold = 0.3; // set this based data & no. of classes
int labelNum = model.label[maxConfidenceIndex];
// reverse map number to name
String targetClassLabel = classLoadMap.get(labelNum); 
LOG.info("classNumber:{}, className:{}; confidence:{}; for text:{}",
        labelNum, targetClassLabel, (maxConfidence), text);
if (maxConfidence < threshold ) {
    LOG.info("Not enough confidence; threshold={}", threshold);
    targetClassLabel = null;
}
return targetClassLabel;
```